# chmod(): Operation not permitted using WSL2

Tags: craft3

Getting this error on a local Craft install with Nitro / Docker.

[image]

I can get it fixed with:

> sudo umount /mnt/c
> sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata

This works until then the error appears again after a while.

Don't know why this happens. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be solved by adding a file called */etc/wsl.conf* (in WSL) which contains:

> [automount]
> options = "metadata"

This is equivalent to running the `sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata` everytime you use WSL.

Also, make sure to set the right permissions to your Craft installation folder:

```
chmod 777 ./.env
chmod 777 ./composer.lock
chmod 777 ./composer.json
sudo chmod -R 777 ./config
sudo chmod -R 777 ./storage
sudo chmod -R 777 ./vendor
sudo chmod -R 777 ./web <- Or public, ...
```